# Is it safe to use 'dd' to "rejuvinate" a hard drive by setting of=if?

Tags: hard-drive, dd

In an effort to prevent some sources of disk rot due to [magnetic flux over time](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/learn-the-dd-command-362506/), I want to read and rewrite all the data on a disk.  It looks like there is a 'dd' command to do this.  Specifically:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sda
```

I have some questions regarding this command, specifically:

1. Is it safe regardless of file system?
2. Does this process do what I expect it to do, i.e. read a sector, then immedietly rewrite it?
3. Does this have the desired practical effects, or is preventing some forms of bit rot in this way snake oil?

Comment: (1) That command looks "safe" as long as every partition is not in use, i.e. not mounted.  It's also slow; estimate two revolutions per sector. (2) Yes.  (3) It does rewrite each sector, so presumably that is the "cure" for the alleged bit rot.

Comment: Magnetic decay takes a long time, so this is only an issue for data you are storing for several years.  Consider using a storage medium design for static storage over a long time.  In any case, this action won't rejuvenate a hard disk itself, it won't make it perform better, it just writes the data fresh.

Comment: How old is your hard drive? Many modern hard drives take care of themselves during idle time.  For example: http://www.wdc.com/wdproducts/library/other/2579-850105.pdf.  Quoting from this doc: *performs
off-line read surface scans while the hard drive is idle, and refreshes weak data*

Comment: @misha256 These disks stay offline for many weeks/months/years at a time, and are used for semi-cold storage.  One of the reasons I started researching this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Empirical approach. I decided to run a test. Short answer: the test didn't show the procedure is unsafe.

---

#### Testbed

`uname -a`:

```
Linux foobar 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.86-1 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

An excerpt from `smartctl -a /dev/sdc`:

```
Model Family:     Western Digital Caviar Blue EIDE
Device Model:     WDC WD5000AAKB-00H8A0
Firmware Version: 05.04E05
User Capacity:    500,107,862,016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
```

Also SMART shows the disk is healthy.

It was connected via USB bridge (to USB 2.0 hub). `lsusb | grep SATA`:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 152d:2509 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. JMS539 SuperSpeed SATA II 3.0G Bridge
```

One partition, almost no unallocated space. `fdisk -l /dev/sdc`:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 465,8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x202b0b89

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1        2048 976773167 976771120 465,8G 83 Linux
```

Healthy ext4 filesystem, unmounted. `file -s /dev/sdc1`:

```
/dev/sdc1: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=… (extents) (large files) (huge files)
```

The filesystem usage was about 20% but:

- it had been extensively used, so the free space was not all zeros for sure;
- I wasn't going to rely on the filesystem anyway, I calculated `md5sum` of the entire device (see below).

---

#### Testing

At first I saved the checksum of the entire device content:

```
md5sum -b /dev/sdc > sdc.before.md5
# the throughput was about 24 MB/s
```

Actual `dd`-ing:

```
dd if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/sdc
# took 800 minutes, 10,4 MB/s

dd if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/sdc bs=128M conv=sync
# 630 minutes, 13,2 MB/s

dd if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/sdc bs=512 conv=sync
# 795 minutes, 10,5 MB/s
```

After each `dd` I run `sync`, then `md5sum -b /dev/sdc`. **All the checksums matched `sdc.before.md5`**.

I also did like `strace dd if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/sdc` and it flooded my terminal with *pairs* of lines like:

```
read(0, "]\203\0\0]\203\1\0]\203\2\0]\203\3\0]\203\4\0]\203\f\0]\203\r\0]\203\30\0"..., 512) = 512
write(1, "]\203\0\0]\203\1\0]\203\2\0]\203\3\0]\203\4\0]\203\f\0]\203\r\0]\203\30\0"..., 512) = 512
```

or (for the large `bs`)

```
read(0, "A\260_4\245\316\273\321p\203\331\250\3022\354\303\6\30\233\366\345\237\303\244\fx\10@=0\221+"..., 134217728) = 134217728
write(1, "A\260_4\245\316\273\321p\203\331\250\3022\354\303\6\30\233\366\345\237\303\244\fx\10@=0\221+"..., 134217728) = 134217728
```

---

#### Conclusions and answers

> 1. Is it safe regardless of file system?

The checksum remains the same and there is nothing filesystem-specific here. Overwriting data with the same data should be safe.

Note: this is true for magnetic drives which overwrite sectors directly. SSDs on the other hand (and I'm not sure if all of them) need to erase a sector (or multiple sectors at once) before it can be written again. The same logical sector may be written to a different physical "cell" etc. In case of power failure this may lead to data corruption (or may not, I know little about precautions in SSDs). You mentioned magnetic flux so I guess SSDs are out of scope anyway.

> 2. Does this process do what I expect it to do, i.e. read a sector, then immediately rewrite it?

`strace` shows this is exactly what happens. Buffers may delay writes but it seems that every sector that is read will be rewritten sooner or later.

I can think of an "optimization" (in OS or in HDD firmware) that would compare a write request to cached reads and might discard the write as unnecessary if the data is already there. It could make your procedure pointless. However, it seems unlikely because:

- the match would rarely occur unless you deliberately want it to happen;
- the cache not large enough would make no difference for large `bs` values.

So if in doubt then just use large `bs`. Large `bs` is good for performance as well.

> 3. Does this have the desired practical effects, or is preventing some forms of bit rot in this way snake oil?

I agree with one of the comments:

> It does rewrite each sector, so presumably that is the "cure" for the alleged bit rot.

Still, to confirm this in practice we need statistical analysis of many disks (some "rejuvenated", some not) over a long time. My single test cannot answer this.